# Is there anyway to create an IPA file without Mac/XCode?

Tags: ios, app-store, ipa

Basically the title. Is there any way to create a `.ipa` file without using a Mac?

Answer (score 0):

basically, an IPA file is just a zip file, so you just have to know tree and files to put it into and then zip it and rename from .zip to .ipa and it is done.

Comment: good to know! is there a guide on how to format the files properly avalible?

Comment: it also seems that each IPA file has a unique binary. is this replicatable on windows/Linux?

Answer (score 0):

You can find more information at 'The iPhone wiki' site and search IPA File Format.
The IPA format is for iOS devices and contains the binary to be run (2 binaries when creating application that can run on 32 and 64 bits).